# What kind of username should be allowed?

Tags: regex, string

I think this is a quite personal taste of question, but as I am designing of how the structure and what characters should be allowed for the username on my site, I started thinking, am I too harsh? What should be  restricted and what not?

This is my username rules:

- must begin with a-z A-Z
- a-z A-Z 0-9 . _ is allowed
- must be between 3 - 20 characters
- Cannot end in a space
- Cannot contain two spaces in a row
- Must begin with a-zA-Z0-9 after the space

What is generally a good aspect of the username? Am I too harsh? Am I to stricted? Should I let other characters after spaces, etc.

This is my regex, if anyone is interested:

```
/^(?=.{3,20}$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.^]*(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
```

Comment: You make the website, so it's really up to you.

Comment: Yeah I know - but as I said, I don't want to be to harsh nor annoy the user when he registers simply off my username rules.

Comment: I don't have any suggestions, so I won't post an answer. In general, these rules look pretty standard and I wouldn't think a user would be annoyed by them.

Comment: I think you should better ask this at http://ux.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I decided to go with the pattern described on the topic. It is "acceptable" so to say.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the username in a url, apply slug rules to it. You can find some implementations here : http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Generate_a_url_slug

Comment: As a notable example, SO doesn't restrict you to that; it's just that the slug in the URI only reflects Latin letters and numbers, but you can easily use more than that.